# Meteor.Render or Template?

Tags: meteor

Just wondering when rendering a list of items.
 
Is it best for the performance to use Meteor.RenderList and Meteor.Render, or should I try to use Templates as much as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use Template {{#each}} and Meteor.render with a backbone router.
i make a function wrap Meteor.render like this

```
render: (where, which, options) ->
    self = @
    self.options = options
    $ where.empty().html Meteor.render Template[which]
```

then inside backbone router it looks like

```
routes:
    '': 'home'

home: ->
    render 'body', 'page-home'
```

and a page-home.html include template and {{#each}} to get my list.

```
<template name="page-home">
    {{> module-streams-list}} blah blah blah
</template>
```

i want to know how people deal page Meteor.render/Meteor.renderList with routing too.